# Rails: InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied for relation schema_migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In my rails app, I am using `postgresql` as my adapter in `database.yml` file. I want to rename the database and reassigned them to a different owner. So i went ahead and changed my postgres database by running:

```
ALTER DATABASE old_name RENAME TO new_name;
CREATE ROLE new_role WITH PASSWORD 'pw123';
ALTER USER new_role CREATEDB;
ALTER USER new_role LOGIN;
```

Then I also modified my `database.yml` file accordingly

After all that, when i run the app again, the error: `InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied for relation schema_migrations`

This new role has the exact same privilege of the previous owner, but I don't know why it is yelling at the new owner.

I believe I am missing a tiny thing here, but i would not figure out what. So what should i do to let my app accept the new postgresql changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database has changed ownership, but the objects in it have not. So the schema still belongs to the old user, and the new user has no permissions on it.

When it comes to permissions and ownership, databasea are objects like all other objects. To use an analogy, you don't own everything *in* a house just because you own the house.

The `REASSIGN OWNED` SQL command can change ownership of all objects in a database.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain a little bit more about this? Why does the object and the database's ownership are separated? What is the point of designed it this way.